# How do I detrend this (non-linear) time series before differencing?

Tags: time-series, stationarity, trend

I have a variable that looks like this (after taking natural log):
[image: graph]

I can't run stationarity tests as there are clearly structural changes in the data. How can I get around this – am I supposed to use dummy variables here? Would I include them in any VAR / VECM model that I'd run with this variable?